# Save selected state of UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell when dismiss the view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

How can I save the selected state of `UICollectionView` inside an `UITableViewCell`?

For more details, I have an `UITableView` with 5 sections and each section has only 1 cell, I put another `UICollectionView` into the cell of the table view and whenever I select an item of collection view cell it will highlight with a red background.

Now I wanna save the selection state for the collection view even if I dismiss the view controller then open it again it must display the correct selected item and I think I will use UserDefaults for saving. But I noticed that when I select an item of collection view in another section it always saves the same index with the first section of the table view.

Here is my code for saving the selected index path to an array, can you please tell me where's my mistake:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let strData = itemFilter[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.item]
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SDFilterCollectionCell

        cell?.filterSelectionComponent?.bind(title: strData.option_name!, style: .select)
        cell?.backgroundColor = .red
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        arrSelectedIndex.append(indexPath)
    }
```

and when deselect:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let strData = itemFilter[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.item]
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SDFilterCollectionCell

        cell?.filterSelectionComponent?.bind(title: strData.option_name!, style: .unselect)
        cell?.backgroundColor = .white
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        if arrSelectedIndex.count > 0 {
            arrSelectedIndex = arrSelectedIndex.filter({$0 != indexPath})
        }else {
            arrSelectedIndex.removeAll()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you want to save `arrSelectedIndex` in `userdefault`, so get `arrSelectedIndex` from `userdefault`.
if you have collectionView in each section of UITableView then with `arrSelectedIndex` save the `indexpath` of table section as well.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SDFilterCollectionCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        // color the background accordingly
        if arrSelectedIndex.contains(indexPath) {
            // selected state
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
        } else {
            // non-selected state
            cell.backgroundColor = .white
        }

        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing now. But as I said, the indexPath saved is wrong. For example, if I save one `indexPath` of `UICollectionView` in section 0 of `UITableView` all items with same indexPath in other table view sections will display in the selected state too.